# Debugging jasmine-node tests with node-inspector

Tags: debugging, node.js, jasmine

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible? Most of the sample for node-inspector seemed geared toward debugging an invoked webpage. I'd like to be able to debug jasmine-node tests though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up writing a little util called toggle:

```
require('tty').setRawMode(true);
var stdin = process.openStdin();

exports.toggle = function(fireThis)
{
    if (process.argv.indexOf("debug")!=-1)
    {
        console.log("debug flag found, press any key to start or rerun. Press 'ctrl-c' to cancel out!");
        stdin.on('keypress', function (chunk, key) {
            if (key.name == 'c' && key.ctrl == true)
            {
                process.exit();
            }
            fireThis();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Running, press any key to rerun or ctrl-c to exit.");
        fireThis();
        stdin.on('keypress', function (chunk, key) {
            if (key.name == 'c' && key.ctrl == true)
            {
                process.exit();
            }
            fireThis();
        });



    }
}
```

You can drop it into your unit tests like:

```
var toggle = require('./toggle');

toggle.toggle(function(){

    var vows = require('vows'),
    assert = require('assert');

    vows.describe('Redis Mass Data Storage').addBatch({

....
```

And then run your tests like: node --debug myfile.js debug. If you run debug toggle will wait until you anything but ctrl-c. Ctrl-c exits. You can also rerun, which is nice.

w0000t.

Answer (score 32):

In short, just debug jasmine-node:

```
node --debug-brk node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js spec/my_spec.js
```

If you look at the source of the `jasmine-node` script, it just invokes `cli.js`, and I found I could debug that script just fine.

I wanted to use node-inspector to debug a CoffeeScript test.  Just adding the `--coffee` switch worked nicely, e.g.

```
node --debug-brk node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js --coffee spec/my_spec.coffee
```

Comment: Actually, this seems to work fine. Just press 'Resume script execution' button after loading debugger. This takes you to the first breakpoint. I'm not sure why my first tests exited instead.

Comment: it is important NOT to specify --autotest command line option because it makes jasmine-node spawn child processes which are not debugable by default, without this option, it works nice

Comment: if it helps others - i think with the updated node inspector: `node-debug /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js spec/`

Comment: As of the date of my comment this works `node --inspect --debug-brk -i ./node_modules/jasmine-node/lib/jasmine-node/cli.js test-jasmine/` as @xorcus mentioned you can't use --autotest.

Answer (score 4):

My uneducated guess is that you'd need to patch jasmine, I believe it spawns a new node process or something when running tests, and these new processes would need to be debug-enabled.

I had a similar desire and managed to get expressso working using Eclipse as a debugger:
http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/af35b025eb801f43

…but I realised: if I needed to step through my code to understand it, I probably need to refactor the code (probably to be more testable), or break my tests up into smaller units.

Your tests is your debugger.

Comment: Apparently not true. See Ian's answer.

Comment: I also believe node-inspector does not work with jasmine-node because jasmine-node spawns child processes and node-inspector does not handle that. Searching for a solution gives a hint that process.debug_port must be set to a unique value for each child process, but that requires tampering with jasmine-node source code, I guess