# How to debug by jasmine node without node inspector

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I am using [jasmine node](https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node) for testing and I want to put a debugger.
Because I am in a remote box via ssh, I can't use node inspector. What is my options?

Possible duplication:

[Debugging jasmine-node tests with node-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162920/debugging-jasmine-node-tests-with-node-inspector)

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21677374/30946, see the section about ssh proxy.