# Debugging karma-jasmine tests with node-inspector

Tags: node.js, debugging, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, node-inspector

Almost the same question as [Debugging jasmine-node tests with node-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162920/debugging-jasmine-node-tests-with-node-inspector) BUT does anyone know how to use node-inspector with karma?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install the node-inspector globally from NPM:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

Then start the node-inspector and background the process (use fg to bring it back to the foreground and kill %1 to stop it):

```
node-inspector &
```

And then start your test runner like in debug mode this

```
node --inspect ./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start
```

Then connect to the inspector from your local loopback. To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
    chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/e771f282-5e94-4247-ac1c-89d7dc035129

If all goes well, you’ll see some developer tools from which to begin debugging.

Comment: Cool, I've been working on another project for the last few weeks so it may take me a little while to try this out, but this sounds right.  Thanks!

Comment: No rush ;) If it works let me know (and accept the answer) else I'd be glad to help.

Comment: @chadoh Yes, although I can't remember for the life of me why I asked this question -- it doesn't make sense because you can't debug any of the code running in the browser via node-inspector.

Comment: How are you debugging the  code? The files aren't appearing in my node inspector, and placing `debugger` statements in my code doesn't seem to do anything, the tests just run.