# Debugging unit tests with node-karma

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Most of the articles I've seen on how to debug unit tests with Karma assume you're running Karma in a browser, such as [this one](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/debugging-karma-unit-tests/) I'm running Karma tests with raw node, in my Linux console with PhantomJS.

Is it possible to debug the tests without running them in a browser?

I've also tried [using node-inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595202/debugging-karma-jasmine-tests-with-node-inspector) but the tests aren't stopping at the `debugger;` statements I place in them. Running `node debug ./path/to/karma start` stops the debugger at places in karma's code, but not in my tests.